# Ubuntu 17.10 LIVE USB Firmware Bug TSC_DEADLINE

Tags: boot, usb, 17.10, live-usb, initramfs

I've searched for this error and I couldn't find any solutions to fix the problem.

I want to install Ubuntu 17.10 with my USB Stick. I've been using that laptop for over 3 years now and I did't have any problems installing Ubuntu or other distros with that same USB Drive and on that same computer. The BIOS is up-to-date as of the manufacturer. I did install the same ISO that I am using of Ubuntu 17.10 a while ago and I did a reformat to reinstall Windows for a while and now I want to go back to Ubuntu.

The complete error I get :

> [ 0.000000] [Firmware Bug] : TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata: please update microcode to version: 0x20 (or later)
>
> BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-19ubuntu2) built-in shell (ash)
>
> Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
>
> (initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system

As I said, even if there is an error for the microcode, it is the same ISO I am using to install Ubuntu 17.10 on the same hardware and I just don't get why it is doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue, it was because my USB key wasn't well formatted. I did use it for other live install OS and it did something to the drive.

What I had to do to fix the issue was to use Rufus on my Windows PC and uncheck `Quick Format` to force Rufus to go through the drive.

Now everything is fine and I am answering using my newly installed Ubuntu 17.10.